# How to make multiple BETWEEN statements not knowing the quantity of them beforehand? (detecting country by IP range)

Tags: sql, sql-server, geolocation, ip, between

I have Ip2LocationLite database with ip_from, ip_to, country_code columns.

All IP's are in decimal format (converted using a function).

So I have to detect those users with IP addresses from certain country.
For example, Russia has over 3 thousands IP ranges and I want to search through all of them.

Script looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[USERINFO] as UserInfo
WHERE (SELECT gaminator.dbo.IPAddressToInteger (UserInfo.LastIp)) BETWEEN
    (
        SELECT [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1].ip_from FROM [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1]
        WHERE [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1].country_code = 'RU'
    )
    AND
    (
        SELECT [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1].ip_to FROM [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1]
        WHERE [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1].country_code = 'RU'
    )
```

The last thing gives error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

This is because BETWEEN expects one diapason instead of 3 thousands diapasons.

How to program this so it makes 3 thousands BETWEEN's instead? (according to the number of diapasons to be checked)

Comment: Can you show a few rows from those tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a little tricky to answer these questions without a few sample records and the expected output.  But if I've understood your schema correctly you can use a join instead of the sub queries.

**Example**

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [dbo].[USERINFO] as UserInfo
        INNER JOIN [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1] AS ipRange     ON UserInfo.LastIp BETWEEN ipRange.ip_to AND ipRange.ip_from
WHERE   
    ipRange.country_code = 'RU'
;
```

Comment: You understood everything right and saved my day. Thank you very much! I feel like using ip2location database is elementary now.

Comment: Excellant.  Glad I could help.  For more on JOINS see this [article, from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Get the `min/lowest` value from your first sub-query and the `max/highest` value from your second sub-query to avoid the error and if you want to use them as parameters for your `BETWEEN` clause.

If your IP addresses are canonical or can be ordered numerically, you may get the lowest IP value by sorting them in ASC order and select the first row  (i.e. `SELECT TOP 1`) and to get the highest IP value by sorting them in DESC order and select the first row also.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try try this..

```
sELECT * FROM [dbo].[USERINFO] as UserInfo
WHERE (SELECT gaminator.dbo.IPAddressToInteger (UserInfo.LastIp)) BETWEEN
    (
        SELECT min([ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1].ip_from )FROM [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1]
        WHERE [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1].country_code = 'RU'
    )
    AND
    (
        SELECT max([ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1].ip_to) FROM [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1]
        WHERE [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1].country_code = 'RU'
    )
```